# How to convert float to int in smarty

Tags: php, smarty

As i am new to smarty, I am not at able to convert floating number to  int.
Ex: 12.234 => 12
please help me if u find any solution

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why don't you cast it before attaching it to the view. There is no reason to pass the view data that needs to be further processed.

```
$int = (int) $float;

$smarty->assign(array(
   'number' = $int
));
```

If you really must get the integer portion of a float using Smarty, try this...

```
{$number|string_format:"%d"}
```

That is like PHP's [`printf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php).

Comment: I need to convert in .tpl(template)?

Comment: @sandeep: No, this is *before* you assign the variable itself; in your `.php` file.

Comment: ya i got it. But i need to change in tpl file.I don have access to .php file.

Comment: There is a perfect reason to pass data that needs to be processed: If you work on a modularized system (e.g. a blog or shop), you might want to get a small change like this done in a template change, without writing a module, overriding the controller and caring about future updates. Anyway, +1 for naming both solutions. :)

Answer (score 5):

Also you should be able doing this: {$variable|intval}

Comment: Works great. Cleaner solution and seems more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

this might work give a try

```
(string)((int)$float)
```

that too check this link

http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=61912

Comment: Why cast to `string`?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done:

```
{$converted = settype($myVar, 'integer')}
```

You'll need to assign the return value of settype, bool, else the value will be displayed in the UI.